# How to get input value from input type="hiden" in loop ngFor angular 10

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular so this question is probably too simple, but I've been stuck on this for a while now and haven't found the answer.

I have a form that uses a list of a product object, and when I submit this form I would like to get the ID value that is in an input type="hidden" but I can't at all.

```
 <form  (ngSubmit)="buildCarShopping()">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="text-uppercase">stock</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-uppercase">price</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-uppercase">quantity</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-uppercase">buy</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of listProduct; let i = index; ">
          <input type="hidden" name="productid" [(ngModel)]="products[i]"/>
          <td class="text-uppercase"> <i class="bi bi-graph-up-arrow m-2 h4"></i>{{product.name}}</td>
          <td class="text-uppercase">$ {{product.price}}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" class="text-center" name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="quantity[i]">
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="bi bi-cart-check h5" role="button"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-buy text-uppercase">payment</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My component:

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  public listProduct: Product[];

  private products: number[] = [];
  private quantity: number[] = [];

  constructor(private service: ProductService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.getProducts().subscribe(
      (listProduct: Product[]) =>{
      this.listProduct = listProduct;
    },
      (error) => console.error(error)
    );
  }

  buildCarShopping(){
    console.log("quantity: " + this.quantity);
    console.log("products: " + this.products);
  }

}
```

my object:

```
export interface Product {
  id: number
  name: string
  family: string
  price: number
}
```

I tried several ways but the arry is always empty

Comment: Have you imported `FormsModule` in your `AppModule`?

Comment: yes it is there, my quantity array works normally.

Comment: What is the value of products and quantity? Where are you storing the values?

Comment: @asnakhan are number, I'm keeping it in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

your template does not have access to the private variables `products` and `quantity`. Also I don't see where you store anything in `products`, so for example for your first `product of listProduct`, `products[0]` is not defined.

Comment: I saw that, and changed it, but even before with the 'private' attribute, the quantity array showed values.

Maybe it wasn't clear what I want, when the user clicks the buy button, I want to receive the 'product id' and 'quantity', that's all